# Are there any risks to leaving my xbox one on all the time?

Tags: xbox-one

I'm running my DVR (TiVo) through the Xbox one, as is recommended.  But my wife doesn't want the extra steps of turning on the xbox and selecting "watch TV" every time she wants to watch something.

By leaving the xbox on all the time, it becomes transparent, so the DVR is full screen when she turns it on.  The xbox shell is (ironically) most hidden if it's always on.

Is there any risk or reason to bother with turning it off when not in use (other than electricity use - I'm already considering and weighing that cost in dollars and environmental impact.)

Comment: As with any device: The longer it runs the higher the risk of mechanical parts failing (e.g. ball bearings of the fans will get louder and will eventually fail completely).

Answer (score 5):

Well, there is always the risk of overheating, but I think that is more preoccupying when used actively. Appart of that, there is no real "immediate" risk of your device. But be aware that normal weariness, of the constant use of the device (like all machines), will reduce the lifespan of the disk/fans/mechanical parts. (Yes, *some* machines use more power cycling on/off than they do in constant use, but I don't think that's likely the case with a gaming console.)

TL;DR: if you leave your device in a good ventilated place to dissipate the heat and periodical dust clean ups, there isn't any risk, but your device may not last as long if it's constantly used.